# Are you able to become Jarl in any of the given cities?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've had a fascination with the different titles you could aquire and was wondering if one could possibly become Jarl in, say Markarth, Solitude, or Whiterun?

Answer (score 11):

It is not possible to supplant any of the existing NPCs as Jarl in the base game. (I wouldn't put it past someone having created a mod to do so, however)

The closest you can get is to become "Thane", which you can do for each of the 9 holds, and will earn you a Housecarl (a la Lydia) and let you clear your bounty from the relevant hold guards, once.

Comment: Not sure if OP is interested based on his response comment, but if anyone in the future reading this is, there _is_ a [mod that lets you be High King of Skyrim](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/64018/). While it's not exactly what OP was asking for, it is a similar position and may also be interesting to those wishing to become Jarl.

Comment: @Drew As seen in ["Unfortunately, I am the high king of Skyrim"](http://imgur.com/gallery/6Zl7k).

Answer (score 2):

Vanilla-wise, there is no way to become Jarl of any city (as unfortunate as that is).

If you use mods there is a specific mod for Skyrim (not SE), [that allows you to become the Jarl of Ivarstead](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/51633/?) (which isn't a major city, but allows you to simulate a Jarl-like lifestyle)

Answer (score 2):

There's no way in vanilla. However, there is a mod to become High King of Skyrim. This would then force all other Jarls to report to you...the Jarl of Jarls.

(Oldrim) Become High King of Skyrim: http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/41087/?
(SSE) Become High King of Skyrim: http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/2152/?

Comment: Become high king is also available for the Xbox One: https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/4057214